# How to ignore comman inside field while loading csv file into a table

Tags: mysql

I have a `csv` file. I need to load the content into a table. Some fields contains comma inside, but I face errors in these fields. The command truncate the field in this comma. How can improve my command to ignore the commas inside the fields values. Here is my SQL command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/myfile.csv'
IGNORE
INTO TABLE db.table
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6);
```

EDIT: My csv file fields are not enclosed by `"`

EDIT: Example of the data in the csv:

```
col1  |  col2  |  col3  |  col4  |  col5  |  col6
------------------------------------------------------------
1111  |  2222  |  3333  |  4444  |  5555  |  firstname, lastname
```

Stored in MySQL in `col6` as:

```
"firstname, lastname" .. followed by all the next fields until the column is filled and truncated.
```

Comment: Your command already specifies `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`. If you have commas in fields which are not quoted, there is no way for you to load them unless you first edit the file to correct the data.

Comment: Post a sample of the data illustrating the errant records.

Comment: You're CSV file is not a CSV file if you're not escaping or quoting your fields appropriately. (Fix your input file)

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: My csv does not contain double qoutation. How can I add them ?

Comment: @user1810868 Impossible to say without seeing the data. It is possible to fix under certain circumstances with a stream editor or regular expression, or you might be in for manual editing.

Comment: @ Michael Berkowski: see my edit plz

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

### Option 1

Ask for a valid [RFC 4180](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDsQFjAA&url=https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180&ei=FmjSUKi3GYrAswaEy4DACQ&usg=AFQjCNEAoOXkSPh2XnTMXwniiQ4zh527iA&sig2=MolFFrutxV6p0XqViewGBQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.Yms) CSV File and not a nice Text File

### Option 2

Followed by [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) Syntax you can do this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/myfile.csv'
IGNORE
INTO TABLE db.table
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
( col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, @firstname, @lastname )
SET col6 = CONCAT_WS( ' ', @firstname, @lastname );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using Excel Macros. Use these steps:

1. Open the Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11).
2. From the Editor, go to: `Insert > Module`.
3. Paste the Macro shown below
4. Close the script editor
5. Go to Excel and run your macro from: `Tools > Macro > Macros`. You
   should see a macro named `CSVFile` selected. Click Run.
6. You will see a `Save As` window. Enter a name for your sheet and save
   it.The new sheet will add "" to every field.

The Macro code is:

```
Sub CSVFile()
Dim SrcRg As Range
Dim CurrRow As Range
Dim CurrCell As Range
Dim CurrTextStr As String
Dim ListSep As String
Dim FName As Variant
FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "CSV File (*.csv), *.csv")
ListSep = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
  If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Set SrcRg = Selection
  Else
    Set SrcRg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  End If
Open FName For Output As #1
For Each CurrRow In SrcRg.Rows
  CurrTextStr = ìî
For Each CurrCell In CurrRow.Cells
  CurrTextStr = CurrTextStr & """" & CurrCell.Value & """" & ListSep
Next
While Right(CurrTextStr, 1) = ListSep
  CurrTextStr = Left(CurrTextStr, Len(CurrTextStr) - 1)
Wend
Print #1, CurrTextStr
Next
Close #1
End Sub
```

Reference: http://www.markinns.com/articles/full/export_excel_csvs_with_double_quotes